# Give permissions to Hudson / build fails due to 'no permission'

Tags: linux, permissions, hudson

In my Hudson job, I need to run a command (android update project) before my ant build, it fails with 'no permission'. 
According to the Hudson docs the commands are run as a newly created user ('hudson') which I found in the /etc/passwd:

```
...
mysql:x:104:111:MySQL Server,,,:/nonexistent:/bin/false
jetty:x:117:130::/usr/share/jetty:/bin/false
hudson:x:118:65534::/var/lib/hudson:/bin/bash
```

How can I allow this user to execute that command?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say at this point. Login to the box, do `$ sudo su - hudson` to swtich to the hudson user, issue whatever command is failing, and take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

In linux you can write an sh file where you can specify the commands to be executed.
Exeute the file like this.
./file_name.sh